# how can i set Image directly on UIView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, addsubview

Can any body tell me how can I set Image directly on `UIView` ?
Here is my code:

```
 UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]init];
 [view setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Comment: you don't want to use UIImageView ?

Comment: you need to use a UIImageView

Comment: You can set it as background
aView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourimage.png"]];

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
UIView *view=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]]];
```

Hope this is help you.

Answer (score 11):

This is very simple to do. Try:

```
UIView * view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin_x, origin_y, width, height)]; 
UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"a.png"]];
[view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release];
```

You can also play with the `UIImageView`'s **frame** property to move it around in your `UIView`. Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 4):

```
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"320_480clouds_background.png"]];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
        [imageView release];
```

Hope this help you

Answer (score 4):

Swift version :

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 200))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myImage")!)
```

Swift 3:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 640, height: 200))
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "myImage")!)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try this :

```
UIView *aView=[[UIView alloc]init];

UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"anImage.png"]];
aView.backgroundColor = background;
[background release];
```

Comment: but for good practice you should use UIImageView for displaying images

Answer (score 2):

Here I am assigning the CGImage to the contents property of layer which accepts CGImage or NSImage. You can only assign CGImage or NSImage to contents property.

```
layerView.layer.contents = UIImage(named: "Mario.png")?.cgImage
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation around why your code solves the OP's problem, and why it's better than the answers already given. This may help - [answer]

Comment: I wouldn't say that it is better everyone's answer but it is just another way you can do it.

Comment: Even so, an explanation of how it differs would be nice.

Comment: Am assigning the CGImage to the contents property of layer which accepts CGImage or NSImage. You can only assign CGImage or NSImage to contents property.

Comment: This I have done using object of CALayer on the layerView which is low-level object of UIKit.